# How to select a column from a table and another column from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Trying to make a database that has one table for a question and a table for answers to that question.

How to select a question (from poll_question) and the answers (from poll_answer) to that question?

```
CREATE TABLE poll_question(Id_question int primary key not null, question varchar(60));

CREATE TABLE poll_answer(Id_answer int primary key not null, answer varchar(100));

INSERT INTO poll_question(Id_questao, questao)
VALUES(1,"What kind of paper is allowed in tommorows exam?");

INSERT INTO poll_answer(Id_answer,answer)
VALUES(1,"A4 squared sheet");

INSERT INTO poll_answer(Id_answer,answer)
VALUES(2,"A4 lined sheet");
```

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You need to use/add "Id_question" as reference in the "poll_answer" as a foreign key to establish the JOIN between tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `poll_answer` table is incomplete. It needs another column which indicates which question each answer belongs to e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE poll_answer(Id_answer int primary key not null, Id_question int, answer varchar(100));
INSERT INTO poll_answer(Id_answer,Id_question,answer)
VALUES(1,1,"A4 squared sheet"),
(2,1,"A4 lined sheet");
```

Then you can find the answers to a given question with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT q.question, a.answer
FROM poll_question q
JOIN poll_answer a ON a.Id_question = q.Id_question
```

Output:

```
question                                            answer
What kind of paper is allowed in tommorows exam?    A4 squared sheet
What kind of paper is allowed in tommorows exam?    A4 lined sheet
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8D4QqTZWgkq2wumzz3TKxo/0)